# Promise.all API calls, distinguish which threw error and reject only one

Tags: node.js, api, asynchronous, es6-promise

Information needed: Using NodeJS framework, Promises.all used with API calls only so asynchronous code

So the bases of my problem lies where I need to create two API calls, let's call them A and B. It is guaranteed that A will either return data or a 404 and B will either return an empty array, data or a 404 (but here the 404 means invalid input, while in API call A, it actually means no resource found). My question is that if A does return a 404, the Promise.all will reject and jump into the catch block as it would normally.

My desired functionality is, if API call A returns a 404, I want API call B to continue and retrieve that data, continuing with my code. Is there a way to distinguish or even separately catch the errors thrown by the two API calls and then carry on if one resolves??

Sample code currently looks like this:

```
function(param) {
  const A = apiCallA();
  const B = apiCallB();

  return Promise.all([A, B])
  .then( ([resA, resB]) => {
    // If resA is null, catch the error but continue with
    // resB. If this is null also Promise.reject('both API calls failed')

    // else if both resA && resB != null, do some stuff and resolve
  })
  .catch( (err) => {
    // Here is where my question lies. The err object can be either from API call A or B.
    // How would I distinguish this?
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options.

1. You can catch the error from API call A before the `Promise.all()` and turn it into a successful request but tagged approrpiately, allowing the `Promise.all()` to finish.
2. You can use [`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) to get both results, regardless of success or failure.

For the first option, you could put a `.catch()` handler on `apiCallA()` that will turn any rejection into a resolve, but will resolve with the error object which you can then later check if you need to:

```
function(param) {
  const A = apiCallA().catch(err => { return {err} });
  const B = apiCallB();

  return Promise.all([A, B]).then( ([resA, resB]) => {
      // you can check if resA succeeded here
      if (resA instanceof Error) {
          // resA actually failed
          console.log(resA);
      }
  }).catch( (err) => {
      // you would only get here if resB failed
  });
}
```

For the second option, you use `Promise.allSettled()`:

```
function(param) {
  const A = apiCallA();
  const B = apiCallB();

  return Promise.allSettled([A, B]).then( ([resA, resB]) => {
    // check both resA.status and resB.status
    if (resA.status === "fulfilled") {
       console.log(resA.value);
    }
    if (res === "fulfilled") {
       console.log(resB.value);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: The second option ```Promise.allSettled()``` sounds pretty much perfect. Could you describe it a bit more? The MDN docs ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled ) left me with some questions. Will I be looking out for the literals 'fulfilled' and 'rejected'? Can I still add a catch block? EDIT: I see now you have updated the answer. I will try this as, programmatically and logic wise, looks EXACTLY what I need.

Comment: @MariosYiannakou - I added a code example of `Promise.allSettled()`

Comment: @MariosYiannakou - If this answered your question, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.

Comment: Your first solution works better as Promise.allSettled was not recognised as a function.Not sure if I am missing something there. Just wanted to let anyone else reading this know.

Comment: @MariosYiannakou - What version of nodejs are you running?  I think `Promise.allSettled()` was added in node v12.9.0.

Comment: Yes, turns out I typed it a bit too fast, my code editor didn’t manage to auto fill and had a spelling error.